# IndexedDB: upgrade with promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, indexeddb

Just started my first project with IndexedDb, and I'm stumped trying to create a system for opening and upgrading the database on first use. I want to use promises (current the [angularJs `$q`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/docs/api/ng/service/$q) service but I'm flexible) to give me some guarantees about trapping any errors that occur and to reduce the mental overhead reasoning about failure modes. My requirements are:

- The consumer calls some function to open and upgrade the database that returns a promise
- The function performs all the upgrades/migrations necessary in sequence. If no errors occur, the promise is resolved with a connection to the database
- If any error occurs at any stage, the promise is guaranteed to be rejected with the error
- Adding a new migration/upgrade step is as easy as defining a function which performs the upgrade, all other concurrency concerns are taken care of by the 'framework'.

Problems I've encountered so far:

- The `onupgraderequired` callback is not called if the DB doesn't need upgrading (so a promise that got resolved on upgrade complete will never be resolved if the DB doesn't need upgrading, and the calling code doesn't know if this will be the case when wiring up callbacks)
- If one upgrade relies on another (e.g. populating a store you just created), you must wait until its `onsuccess` callback is called - so each upgrade needs sequential chaining
- It appears that the delay for a promise to be executed after its predecessor in the chain resolves is enough to mark the 'transaction' as inactive before it's needed again (I think they're scheduled with 'nextTick', which may be the same mechanism that inactivated the transaction).
- **update** if one upgrade relies on another, by the time the `onsuccess` callback of the first is called, the `versionchange` transaction is no longer active.

My current conclusion is that the API is fundamentally hostile to a promises-based approach. My best attempt is below (simplified a bit for easier reading). Where am I going wrong?

```js
var newPromise = function(withDeferred) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    try {
        withDeferred(deferred);
    } catch (err) {
        deferred.reject(err); 
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};

var newTransactionPromise = function(getTransaction) {
    return newPromise(function(deferred) {
        var transaction = getTransaction();

        transaction.oncomplete = function(ev) { deferred.resolve(); };
        transaction.onabort = function(ev) { deferred.reject(transaction.error); };
    });
};

var migrations = [
    function(db) {
        return newTransactionPromise(function() {
            // throws: The database is not running a version change transaction.
            return db
                .createObjectStore("entries", { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true })
                .transaction;
        });
    },
    function(db) {
        return newTransactionPromise(function()
        {
            var entryStore = db.transaction("entries", "readwrite").objectStore("entries");
            entryStore.add({ description: "First task" });
            return entryStore.transaction;
        });
    }
];

var upgradeAndOpen = function() {
    return newPromise(function(deferred) {
        var latest_version = migrations.length;
        var request = indexedDB.open("caesium", latest_version);

        request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
            try {
                // create an already resolved promise to start a chain
                var setupDeferred = $q.defer(); 
                setupDeferred.resolve();
                var setupComplete = setupDeferred.promise;

                for (var v = event.oldVersion; v < latest_version; v++)
                {
                    // Problem: the versionchange transaction will be 'inactive' before this promise is scheduled
                    var nextMigration = migrations[v].bind(this, request.result);
                    setupComplete = setupComplete.then(nextMigration);
                }

                setupComplete["catch"](deferred.reject);
            } catch (err) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
        };

        request.onerror = function(event) { deferred.reject(request.error); };
        request.onsuccess = function(event) { deferred.resolve(request.result); };
    });
};

upgradeAndOpen()["catch"](function(err) { $scope.status = err; });
```

Comment: I had example AngularJS app using promise https://github.com/yathit/feature-matrix it uses my own library ydn-db thought. It may be helpful to get some idea and validate that it is possible, of course.

Comment: Maybe https://gist.github.com/inexorabletash/9675881 helps you. Or https://gist.github.com/inexorabletash/8791448.

Comment: @KyawTun Thanks for the hint but I think these are the relevant lines from your library and it looks like you aren't using promises for the upgrade: https://github.com/yathit/ydn-db/blob/7c780a988bac69d4e88bebce1667d86594a5cba6/src/ydn/db/conn/indexed_db.js#L153-L173

Comment: @Josh Thanks for those links, the first would solve my problem but looks like a proposal for a feature rather than working code? I think the second wraps requests in promises but actually executes them using a synchronous queue which wouldn't work for updates that must be applied on completion of the last (e.g. createStore, insert data). https://gist.github.com/inexorabletash/8791448#file-idbp-js-L67-L74

Comment: @TomCarver you are right. I used event, instead. Sorry.

Comment: it should be `transaction.onabort = function(ev) { deferred...` instead of `transaction.onerror = function(ev) { deferred...`. `onerror` is similar to `window.onerror`. `onabort` is final callback in case of transaction fail, so it is same as `promise.reject`.

Comment: @KyawTun you're right, thanks for the tip, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to avoid all the nastiness of this API and have found a solution that exposes a clean promises-based interface and generalises to any number of database migrations. Key gotchas:

- Schema changes can *only* be performed during a `versionchange` transaction; <del>but data changes *cannot* be performed during a `versionchange` transaction, therefore we must distinguish between data and schema migrations and execute them in different ways, with distinct transactions.</del> **update** data changes *can* be performed during a `versionchange` transaction, but not via the usual `db.transaction('readwrite', ...).objectstore(...)` method - this throws an exception. Instead use a reference to the `versionchange` transaction.
- To allow arbitrary interleaving of schema creation and population, we must treat these as separate migration steps and only attempt one step once the transaction for the previous step has succeeded.
- Explicit transaction management is explicitly prevented by the spec (https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/IndexedDB/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#transaction-concept
  ) which limits the extent to which transactions can be re-used as they are marked inactive once the event loop completes
- Therefore method `.open(dbName, version)` only allows one `versionchange` transaction, once it succeeds it's gone. This method is the only way to create `versionchange` transactions
- Therefore multiple migration steps require multiple successive calls to `.open(dbName, version)`
- `versionchange` transactions block while other database connections are open, so every connection must be closed before attempting the next migration in the chain.

The code I came up with to negotiate all these gotchas is below.

```
var newPromise = function(withDeferred) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    try {
        withDeferred(deferred);
    } catch (err) {
        deferred.reject(err); 
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};

var newTransactionPromise = function(getTransaction) {
    return newPromise(function(deferred) {
        var transaction = getTransaction();

        transaction.oncomplete = function(ev) { deferred.resolve(); };
        transaction.onabort = function(ev) { deferred.reject(transaction.error); };
    });
};

var newMigrationPromise = function(dbName, version, migration) {
    return newPromise(function(deferred) {
        var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, version);

        // NB: caller must ensure upgrade callback always called
        request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
            var db = request.result;
            newTransactionPromise(
                function() {
                    migration(db, request.transaction);
                    return request.transaction;
                })
                .then(function() { db.close(); })
                .then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
        };

        request.onerror = function(ev) { deferred.reject(request.error); };
    });
};

var migrations = [
    function(db, transaction) {
        db.createObjectStore("entries", { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
    },
    function(db, transactionn) {
        db.createObjectStore("entries2", { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
    },
    function(db, transaction) {
        var entryStore = transaction.objectStore("entries");

        entryStore.add({description: "First task"});
    }
];

var upgradeAndOpen = function() {
    return open()
        .then(function(db) {
            var version = db.version;
            db.close(); // this connection will block the upgrade (AFAICT)
            return version;
        })
        .then(function(version) {
            return newPromise(function(deferred) {
                // version when created but empty is v1
                // so after the first migration (index: 0) the version must be 2
                var migrationsPerformed = version - 1;
                var migrationCount = migrations.length;

                var previousMigration = newPromise(function(deferred) { deferred.resolve(); });

                for (var index = migrationsPerformed; index < migrationCount; index++)
                {
                    var performNextMigration = newMigrationPromise.bind(this, "caesium", index+2, migrations[index]);
                    previousMigration = previousMigration.then(performNextMigration);
                }

                previousMigration.then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
            });
        })
        .then(open);
};

var open = function() {
    return newPromise(function(deferred) {
        var request = indexedDB.open("caesium");

        request.onsuccess = function(ev) { deferred.resolve(request.result); };
        request.onerror = function(ev) { deferred.reject(request.error); };
    });
};

upgradeAndOpen()
    .then(function() { $scope.status = "completed"; }, function(err) { $scope.status = err; });
```

Comment: Should you reject with active transaction when db opening request fail? Consumer of opening request will do the upgrade using the active transaction and will resolve with database eventually.

Comment: @KyawTun sorry I don't follow what you mean - which line are you talking about?

Comment: `request.onupgradeneeded = function() {deferred.reject(request.transaction)}`

Comment: @KyawTun I'm afraid I can't find that line or one like it anywhere in my code. I only access <code>.transaction</code> properties in order to add <code>eventhandlers</code> to them, and I only <code>reject</code> promises with JS exceptions or the <code>.error</code> properties of requests/transactions.

Answer (score 2):

```
var open = function(name, ver) {
  return new Promise(function(yes, no) {
     var req = indexedDB.open(name, var);
     req.onupgradedneeded = function(res) {
       no(req);
       req.onsuccess = null; // for clarity
     };
     req.onsuccess = function() {
       yes(res.result);
     };
     req.onblocked = no;
  }
});

open('db name', 3).then(function(db) {
  // use db here

 }, function(req) {
   // version upgrade logic here

   if (req instanceof IDBResult) {
    return new Promise(function(yes, no) {
      req.transaction.createObjectStore('store_3');
      req.onsuccess = function() {
        yes(req.result);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: That certainly works for a single upgrade step but doesn't meet my main requirement - chaining of multiple upgrade steps in an easily maintainable way. If you believe the above generalises to multiple upgrade steps (e.g. create 'store_1', insert a value into it, then create 'store_2') then please update your example to show how.

Comment: Look like you will have to open unversioned database and trace back each version. Will that be a good API? Promise helpful here?

Comment: I updated my answer about with a solution that works fine, my only concerns with it are performance (it opens & closes n+2 database connections where n is the number of migrations we need to perform). I think the API design is pretty good, feedback on any specific problems you can see with it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Closure library has [promise wrapper for IndexedDB](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/namespace_goog_db.html). Its open database method [return a promise](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/local_closure_goog_db_db.js.source.html#line119) and everything in IDB is wrapped with promise there.

So it is similar to your idea.

Here is example excerpt from there:

```
  goog.db.openDatabase('mydb', 1, function(ev, db, tx) {
    db.createObjectStore('mystore');
  }).addCallback(function(db) {
    var putTx = db.createTransaction(
        [],
        goog.db.Transaction.TransactionMode.READ_WRITE);
    var store = putTx.objectStore('mystore');
    store.put('value', 'key');
    goog.listen(putTx, goog.db.Transaction.EventTypes.COMPLETE, function() {
      var getTx = db.createTransaction([]);
      var request = getTx.objectStore('mystore').get('key');
      request.addCallback(function(result) {
        ...
      });
  });
```

I have started from there, but resulting API did not work out well, so happen I have written IndexedDB wrapper, using closure library again.

The problem with wrapping everything with promise is not easy to use, you need to track active transaction. As you see, you will have three level of promise for a database query, 1) db opening promise 2) transaction promise 3) request promise.

You can eliminate the first promise by keeping db as reference throughout to your application on global, but the last two will be around.

So mainly, I combine these three promises into one promise on my library.

Comment: I checked the source (http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/local_closure_goog_db_db.js.source.html#line119) and the upgrade is not done with promises (the 'd' variable representing the deferred is only called from the onsuccess and onerror callbacks)

Comment: chaining extra callbacks after the openDatabase call only works because you're not trying to create or delete any object stores; these commands can only be performed during a versionchange transaction (http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBDatabase-createObjectStore-IDBObjectStore-DOMString-name-IDBObjectStoreParameters-optionalParameters), otherwise I'd just do something similar to what you have