# IndexedDB - During upgrade force abort, but with Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, service-worker, indexeddb, idbobjectstore

I used this post: [IndexedDB: upgrade with promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556681/indexeddb-upgrade-with-promises)

And implemented the part here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25565755/15778635

This works for what I need.  the part I am having trouble with is this:

```
var newMigrationPromise = function (dbName, version, migration) {
    return newPromise(function (deferred) {
        var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, version);

        // NB: caller must ensure upgrade callback always called
        request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
            var db = request.result;
            newTransactionPromise(
                function () {
                    var syncUPStore = transaction.objectStore("syncUP");
                    var syncCountRequest = syncUPStore.count();

                    syncCountRequest.oncomplete = function (event) {
                        if (syncCountRequest.result > 0)
                            deferred.reject(syncCountRequest.result + " SyncUp Records exist, database upgrade aborted, keeping at current version.");
                        else {
                            //Good, continue with update
                            migration(db, request.transaction);
                            return request.transaction;
                        }
                    }
                })
                .then(function () { db.close(); })
                .then(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
        };

        request.onerror = function (ev) { deferred.reject(request.error); };
    });
};
```

I have a syncUP object store that has data that needs to be sent to the server when the user goes online.  In this particular case the service worker is installing (because they came online and a change was put on the server) and needs to know if syncUP records exist prior to allowing the service worker to update.  If they do exist then it needs to abort the install until it is empty.

The service worker abort works fine, and the database aborting upgrade works fine if I were to throw an error where `var syncCountRequest = syncUPStore.count();` is.

My question:
How can I check if there are records in the "syncUP" object store and still use the implementation I mentioned above?  I had considered moving the logic to another method, but I found I was having the same issue of not knowing how to handle the reject/resolve.  My Promises knowledge is ok, but not good enough yet to figure it out on my own.

Comment: You cannot use nested promises very well in the onupgradeneeded handler, because you cannot await them, and you cannot attach functionality that only executes later, as the version change transaction available to the upgradeneeded handler will timeout.  I would avoid using promises within upgradeneeded.

Comment: The other [stackoverflow link I included](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25565755/15778635) has an implementation of promises being used to do just what you said it couldn't do.  My problem is interpreting it enough to do it for me also.  It seems to hinge on the "deffered" function to manage it, but I could not figure out how to re-use it for my needs.

Comment: That link uses promises in a pointless manner, primarily just as syntactical sugar. I made the comment because I am telling you, now, again, that you will encounter issues using promises within upgradeneeded and are better off avoiding them.

Comment: You are 100% correct, the problem I face is managing the serviceworker and indexeddb changes when I have a major release with my clients having offline data.  I changed my approach on how to handle this and it seems to be working so far for my needs.  However if I could do a data check on the existing store during the upgrade process and abort the transaction so the upgrade fails.  Then I would be happier.

Comment: You can do this. In on upgradeneeded, if you see that old version was previously present, then you can perform migration requests on the version change transaction that manipulate the data.

Comment: If you have an example of data querying and manipulation inside the onupgradeneeded that somehow keeps the transaction open, I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

a rushed example:

```js
var request = indexedDb.open(...);
request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
  if(conditionShouldDoMigrationFromVersionXToNowIsTrue) {
    migrate(event.transaction);
  }
};

function migrate(versionChangeTransaction) {
  var store = versionChangeTransaction.objectStore('x');
  var request = store.getAll();
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
     var objects = event.target.result;
     for (var object of objects) {
       // do some mutation to the object
       object.x++;
       // write it back
       store.put(object);
     }
  }; 
}
```